# How to auto adjust the rowHeight based on the item in a cell Aggrid

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ag-grid

am using aggrid in my project, and I want to implement an auto-resize function in my rows. Means currently in each of my cell there will be multiple div elements. So If i fix the height of my row, if i add a third div it getting hided or overflowing. How can I prevent this in ag-grid? I need to have padding for div of 10 around the cell as well. I think I should come up with some calculation or is there any property available? Thanks in advance guys.

Currently I have this code for calculation, the return value will eventually passed to my `getRowHeight: this._getRowHeight`:
private _getRowHeight(_params: any): number {
    let maxHeight: number = 100;

```
for (let i in _params.data) {
    if (i != "time" && _params.data[i] instanceof Array) {
        let tempHeight: number = 100 * _params.data[i].length;

        if (tempHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = tempHeight;
    }
}
return maxHeight;
```

}

Data Structure of _params.data[i]:

[image]

When I add a new object into my content, the row height problem occurs. I hope yu guys now have the better idea.

Comment: Ok. So you're assuming that we can see your code because there is a camera in our mind right?

Comment: Hi Chirag, this is a basic doubt. Thought no need of codes. Added the codes CHIRAG

Comment: Yeah, But including some basic codes helps answerer to give you quick responce. :)

Comment: Chirag, added the codes and DS

Answer (score 1):

you can override rowHeight of gridOption as

`gridOptions.rowHeight = $scope.tempRowHeight`

As per dynamic property like

```
$scope.addRow function(heigth) {
    $scope.tempRowHeight = heigth;
    refreshView();
}
```

Comment: I want something like dynamic, means when new items added into the cell the row height should auto change.

Comment: Anurag, its Angular 2 sorry